# How to add a github library to my android project?

Tags: android

I would like to add [this library](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview.git) so that I can use it on my android project but I can't figure out how to.  I get that I'm supposed to clone it but it doesn't say into which directory I should clone it.  I'm also not sure if I should use ant or maven, what those are, and how to do that.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is the project I'm hoping to add it to:
https://github.com/mikeoles/swiftset

Comment: At a glance I couldn't see that a license has been applied to that repository, so be aware of that if you still plan on using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more project i which is forked from bauerca/drag-sort-listview
 is available for drag-sort-listview and dependency of that project is deployed on maven repository

https://github.com/ened/drag-sort-listview

Gradle is available on mvn repository. check this URL

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asia.ivity.android/drag-sort-listview/1.0

**Add this to your android project**

compile group: 'asia.ivity.android', name: 'drag-sort-listview', version: '1.0'

Answer (score 0):

this project is not a library project instead it is an Android app project so what you have to do is to clone the repo https://github.com/mikeoles/SwiftSet.git and open this as an existing Android project.
FYI, you can check android project structure at this link https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the library support gradle. Or copy code to you project(the project has no update in last 5 years).